# undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, methods

i'm trying to show all the videos in my app so when i'm adding a new video and want to redirect to movie_path so i did this in my video controller:

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(video_params)
  if @video.save
    flash[:success] = 'Video added!'
    redirect_to movie_path(@movies)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

it gives me an error:
undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
this is my show page that want to show the video:

```
<% if @videos.any? %>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="player-wrapper"></div>
   <% @videos.in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
     <% group.each do |video| %>
      <% if video %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="yt_video thumbnail">
            <%= link_to image_tag("https://img.youtube.com/vi/#{video.uid}/mqdefault.jpg", alt: video.title,
                                  class: 'img-rounded'),
                        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#{video.uid}", target: '_blank' %>
            <div class="caption">
              <h5><%= video.title %></h5>
              <p>Published at <%= video.published_at.strftime('%-d %B %Y %H:%M:%S') %></p>
              <p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> <%= video.likes %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> <%= video.dislikes %>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

this is movie controller:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all.order(:cached_votes_score => :desc)
  @movies = @movies.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 8)

end

def show
  @reviews = Review.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")
end

def new
  @movie = current_user.movies.build
  @movie = Movie.new 
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end
```

and this is the routes i have:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`nil` don't have method `any?` so you must protect your code against it

instead this line:

```
<% if @video.any? %>
```

write this:

```
<% if @video.try(:any?) %>
```

Comment: well this works fine but i got another error missing required keys: [:id] ...redirect_to movie_path(@movies)

Comment: @AdelAlmaleh In your video controller, you need to remove **require** from strong params. As you are saving a new video you can use params.fetch(:something).permit(:your_params).

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not defined `@videos`, you have defined `@video`, so you should try this:

```
<% if @video.any? %>
```